# Correlation, Independence, and Useful Data Points in a set.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, independence, correlation, confidence-interval

I'll try to be as specific as possible here. This is a problem I'm trying to solve at work. There are two questions:

Question 1: How can I prove I am within a range 95% of the time with 99.99% confidence using a discrete and dependent data set?

Question 2: How many useful data points can I get from a dependent data set to do PDFs with?

Setup:

I have GPS data from flight tests. I can figure out the autocorrelation between each data point and find points that are uncorrelated. Can I used these data points to do the statistics in question 1?

1 data point per flight test ensures independent data, this is best case scenario but it costs more money to do that. I want to get as many useful data points per flight test as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Question (1) needs some clarification, perhaps in terms of GPS data. If (2) means you are trying to approximate the PDF from $n$ indep data points and you want to know how large $n$ must be, then there is no specific answer. Generally speaking, the larger $n$ the more precisely you can estimate the density. Do you have a way to specify how accurately you need to estimate the PDF? I'll illustrate trying to determine a particular distribution with $n = 50, 500, 5000$ in my Answer.

Comment: Can I even do distributions without independent data points? I'm having issues understanding what tools are available for the data I have. It is position data. A point in 2d space. Each point is highly correlated to the last point and the one before that. The biggest question is how to find out how many data points per test i can get for use in making a PDF and confidence interval.

Comment: This seems a mainly separate issue: You might make `autocorrelation function' (ACF) plots of x and y coordinates (separately) to see how many 'lags' it takes for autocorrelation to become minimal; say the max for x and y is lag of 10. Then you can 'thin' the series, using every 10th observation, and the thinned observations will be nearly uncorrelated and (one might hope/check) essentially independent for your purposes. See Addendum to my Answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the population distribution is $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape=5, rate=1/10),$
which might arise if you were adding five independent exponential waiting time distributions (each with rate $1/10$ or mean $10).$

A simple and traditional way to get an idea of the density function from data is to make a histogram. A more modern and sophisticated way is to use a 'kernel density estimator' of the data. (You can google that if you're interested.)

For samples of sizes $n = 50, 500,$ and $5000$ from this distribution, I'll show a histogram of the data and a KDE of the data (red curve) along with
the true density of $\mathsf{Gamma}(5, 1/10)$ in black. As you can see, larger
samples tend to give better approximations of the density function. [In practice, I suppose the true density function might not be known.]

[image]

Here is the R code that produced the figure, in case it is of any use.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
x1 = rgamma(50, 5, 1/10)
hist(x1, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2", main="Sample of 50")
  lines(density(x1), col="red", lwd=2)
  curve(dgamma(x, 5, 1/10), add=T, lwd=2)

x2 = rgamma(500, 5, 1/10)
hist(x2, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2", main="Sample of 500")
  lines(density(x2), col="red", lwd=2)
  curve(dgamma(x, 5, 1/10), add=T, lwd=2)

x3 = rgamma(5000, 5, 1/10)
hist(x3, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.02), col="skyblue2", main="Sample of 5000")
  lines(density(x3), col="red", lwd=2)
  curve(dgamma(x, 5, 1/10), add=T, lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

---

**Addendum on ACF:** Roughly speaking, the autocorrelation for lag $g=10$ 
of a sequence $W_i,$ with $i = 1, \dots, 100,$ is the sample correlation
of $(W_1, W_2, \dots W_{90})$ and $(W_{10}, W_{11}, \dots, W_{100}).$
However, in finding this correlation, sample means and variances for
all 100 observations are used. The ACF function of $W_i$ consists of
autocorrelations for lags $g = 0$ (autocorrelation 1), $g =1, 2, 3, \dots.$
You can google 'autocorrelation' for details.

The program below simulates a Markov Chain $W_i$ over $m= 10,000$ steps, and
makes an ACF plot of the series $W_1, \dots W_{10000}$ for various lags. 
For simplicity, $W_i$'s take only values 0 and 1; the state space of the
chain is $\{0,1\}.$ [This is a simulated weather process for sun=0 and rain=1
during the rainy season in a Mediterranean climate: e.g., TelAviv, San Francisco,
Santiago.]

It seems
that autocorrelations decay to insignificance after about lag 10. [Knowing that it rains today has essentially no predictive value for rain ten days from now.] Then
the second ACF plot of thinned data $W_1, W_{11}, \dots W_{9991}$ shows
essentially no autocorrelations (beyond $g=0).$ Autocorrelations within
the broken blue horizontal bands are taken as insignificant.

```
m = 10000;  w = numeric(m);  n = 1:m
alpha = 0.1;  beta = 0.2  # weather change probabilities
w[1] = 0                  # start with a sunny day
for (i in 2:m)  {
   if (w[i-1]==0)  w[i] = rbinom(1, 1, alpha)
   else            w[i] = rbinom(1, 1, 1 - beta)  
   }
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  acf(w)
  j = seq(1,m, by=10)
  thin = w[j]
  acf(thin)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]